# Simple HTML DOM gets only 1 element

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I'm following a simplified version of the scraping tutorial by NetTuts here, which basically finds all divs with `class=preview`

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/html-parsing-and-screen-scraping-with-the-simple-html-dom-library/comment-page-1/#comments

This is my code. The problem is that when I count `$items` I get only 1, so it's getting only the first div with `class=preview`, not all of them.

```
$articles = array();   
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file('http://net.tutsplus.com/page/76/');

$items = $html->find('div[class=preview]');  
echo "count: " . count($items);
```

Comment: Suggested third party alternatives to [SimpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) that actually use [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) instead of String Parsing: [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), [Zend_Dom](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.dom.html), [QueryPath](http://querypath.org/) and [FluentDom](http://www.fluentdom.org).

Comment: what if you did `$items[] = $html->find('div[class=preview]');` or just declared the array first. It's either not scraping the DOM properly or not storing it properly. maybe try a `var_dump($html->find('div[class=preview]'))`

Comment: You can compare selection syntax for simplehtmldom phpquery and ganon [here](http://scraperblog.blogspot.com/2012/11/choosing-php-html-parser.html). I find that phpquery has the cleanest syntax and is best in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php):

```
$file = file_get_contents('http://net.tutsplus.com/page/76/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($file);
$domx = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodelist = $domx->evaluate("//div[@class='preview']");
foreach ($nodelist as $node) { print $node->nodeValue; }
```