# Getting text out of HTML tags by PHP

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm quite new to programming in PHP and I might have some simple problems, but I haven't found the answer yet over here.
I want to use PHP to obtain the text between the  tags and used Simple HTML DOM for this.
My code looks like this :

```
$html = file_get_contents($base_url . $menu_url);
//print($html);

$students = array();

foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
    $students[] = $element->plaintext;
}
```

But when I run this code it gives me:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in <location> on line <x>
```

Any clear mind who could correct me?

Comment: You have the string `$html`, but you never created a simple_html_dom object.

Comment: [`file_get_contents`](http://us.php.net/file_get_contents) returns a string. You need to create a Simple HTML DOM object from that string, which according to Google is done using [`file_get_html`](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521507/simple-html-dom-gets-only-1-element for a simple example of how to create the object.

Comment: @DCoder, for some reason my code doesn't return HTML when using that. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$html` is a string and not an object. So you can't call methods on it. If you want to parse Html have look around Stackoverflow there are a lot of examples. E.g. [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-xml-with-php) and [Best XML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/).